# Como retornar dados em uma tag <select>?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Possuo uma tabela de produtos, onde um produto pode possuir várias fotos. Quando for selecionado o código na `<select>` ele deve retornar todas as fotos cadastradas. Como faço isso?

Answer (score 2):

fazer uma requisição assíncrona pode ser mais fácil, mas da para fazer em javascript usando o novo atributo do HTML5 "data-*":

```js
function listaFoto(sel) {
  var i = sel.selectedIndex;
  if(i === 0) return;
  
  // dataset.foto é uma nova API do HTML5, se quiser compatibilidade com IE, tente usar "attributes", mas nao testei
  var arrayFotos = sel.options[i].dataset.foto.split(',');
  
  alert(arrayFotos);
}
```

```html
<select id="opcoes" onchange="listaFoto(this)">
  <option value="" data-foto=""></option>
  <option value="1" data-foto="foto1a.jpg,foto1b.jpg,foto1c.jpg">Produto 1</option>
  <option value="2" data-foto="foto2a.jpg,foto2b.jpg,foto2c.jpg">Produto 2</option>
  <option value="3" data-foto="foto3a.jpg,foto3b.jpg,foto3c.jpg">Produto 3</option>
</select>
```